# pear mail.php & namecheap server throwing errors

Tags: php, pear, namecheap

tried to get in contact with name cheap and they couldn't help me only directing me to there support page.

the error im getting is this.

> Failed to connect to mail.privateemail.com :587 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (code: -1, response: )]

the code im using is just a simple php mailer using pear mail.php

```
<?php
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<example@email.com>';
$to = '<someuser@gmail.com>'
$subject = 'hello'; // subject of mail
$body = "Hello world!"; //content of mail

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'mail.privateemail.com ',
        'port' => '587',
        'secure' => false,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'example@namecheap.com',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));

// Send the mail
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

//check mail sent or not
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo '<p>'.$mail->getMessage().'</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Message successfully sent!</p>';
}
```

if anyone has done this before and can offer some advice or help that be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Remove the trailing space from: `'host' => 'mail.privateemail.com '`

Comment: omg no way. how painful. stressing for hours over an extra space! thank you very much.